# How to crop image taken from Android phone's camera?

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I want to crop an image taken from Android phone's camera. The cropped image should contains only the rectangle shaped object(s) within the parent image. Can It be possible in Android please provide some references/tutorials for the same.

Comment: see this link http://shaikhhamadali.blogspot.in/2013/09/capture-images-and-crop-images-using.html

Comment: I list several libraries for image cropping in http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Thanks, my requirement to detect rectangle shaped object first after it crop that rectangle item from the image taken